# c++ multidimensional array multiple data types

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to create a multidimensional array in c++ where there's a string and an int involved. I tried `int test[1][2] = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};` but g++ gave me the following:

```
example.cpp: In function ‘int getServer(std::string)’:
error: too many initializers for ‘int [1][2]’
error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘int’ [-fpermissive]
```

I tried to use `char test[1][2]` as well for the initializer, but this didn't work.

Edit: This will become a rather large multidimensional array and it's needed so that I can get values and store based on a loop control variable which will vary in its length.

Comment: Are you mapping one to another or storing pairs?

Comment: basically trying to store them in pairs to access each value doing something like `test[0][0]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair):

```
std::array<std::pair<std::string, int>, 3> test{{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3}};
```

`std::pair` works with C++03, but the initialization and array type I used are C++11. You can still use a normal array and a bunch of `std::make_pair` calls.

Now you can access each inner element with an index and `first` or `second`:

```
test[0].first //"a"
test[2].second //3
```

Comment: well, I need to be able to use the multidimensional array to get the length (by that, I mean the number of pairs), and also be able to use it in cases like `while (i <= 10) { test[0][i]; i++; }`

Comment: @cellsheet, You can get the number of pairs with `test.size()`. As for your other example, pairs only have two "elements", so `i <= 10` doesn't make sense. And with only two, I can't imagine why you would specifically make it harder to use `[i]` than just `.first`, followed by `.second`.

Comment: there's a specific formula I have to port in which it heavily rely's on the length of the array and stores/access values depending on the loop control variable.       `while (length < test.size()) {
        variable += test[variable2][1];
        variable++;
      }` is an example of part of this formula.

Comment: @cellsheet, The only thing you need to change to make it work is the constant `[1]` to a constant `.second`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not allowed in c++.  An array can only have one type, so specifying an array with two types like that does not actually make sense.

My idea to do this would be to define a struct:

```
struct pair {
    std::string s;
    int i;
}
```

And then define a one dimensional array of type pair.  Then access your elements like `array[0].s`

Comment: To store a collection of multiple types, I would use a [tuple](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) instead of an array.

Answer (score 2):

This generally should not be done in C++.  If you are associating pairs (chars and ints, for example), and want them in an array, you should use a simple struct to associate the two, like

```
struct MyPair {
   char letter;
   int number;
};
```

Then use it like this:

```
MyPair pairAr[2];
MyPair myPair;
myPair.letter = 'a';
myPair.number = 1;
pairAr[0] = myPair;
```

This is generally more a C style.  You also may want to consider making a class which contains the information you want, and using STL collections, like the `Vector` class.